# Find the envelope of the family of straight lines $x \cos α + y \sin α = a \sec α$ , where $α$ is the parameter.

Tags: calculus, matrices

Ok, so here's what I have done I have divided both the sides cosα and then simplified it to

$(x-a) + y\tan \alpha - a\tan^2 \alpha = 0$

I am stuck as to what I should do here... Some help needed.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $$a t^2-y t+(a-x),~ t=\tan \alpha~~~~(1)$$
For the envelope (the fixed curve which is touched by the given family of lines(1)), demand  $B^2=4AC$, in this quadratic. Then we get
$$y^2=4a(a-x)~~~~(2)$$
which is the required envelope.

Comment: Ahh... Sorry, for my dumbass not figuring this out. I am just starting with differential calculus. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Using ODE (Clairaut)

Write the family of lines as
$$y=-x\cot b+2a\csc 2b~~~(1)$$
D.w.r.t $x$, then $y'=-\cot b$ use this in (1) to eliminate $b$
$$y=xy'-a\frac{1+y'^2}{y'}~~~~(2)$$
D. w. r. $x$
$$y'=y'+xy''+a\frac{y''}{y'^2}-ay''~~~~(3)$$
$$\implies y''=0, y'=\pm \sqrt{\frac{a}{a-x}}~~~~(4)$$
Eq(2) is called Clairaut equation, were $y''=0 \implies y'=C$ will give the family of lines (1) as solution. The fixed solution will come from the other equation in (4), Solve it for $y'$ to get
The fixed curve (the envelope) can be found by solving the ODE in (4) as
$$y=\int\sqrt{\frac{a}{a-x}} dx \implies y^2=4a(a-x).$$
No constant is added in the fixed (singular) solution.